# ASIFormDataRequest not Sending JSON data with Image to PHP Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I want to send POST request to server with JSON and image data. I am using the code below but it gives the following error each time I run it -

> { Code = 400; Detail = "Unable to parse JSON in form.request";
>   Response = Error; }

This is the ASIFormDataRequest Request -

```
ASIFormDataRequest *asiRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlForAPI]];
[asiRequest setTimeOutSeconds:60];

NSDictionary *dict1 = [[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:api_username,@"api_username",api_password,@"api_password",@"updateUser",@"method", nil] autorelease];
NSDictionary *dict2 = [[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"13",@"id",nil] autorelease];
NSDictionary *data = [[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:dict1,@"request",dict2,@"methodparam", nil] autorelease];

NSMutableDictionary *requestheaders =[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init] autorelease];
[requestheaders setValue:@"multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-8522EA03-7EA6-446F-9CAB-6EC10511FD22" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
[asiRequest setRequestHeaders:requestheaders];

NSData *jsonData = [data JSONData];
NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
[asiRequest setRequestHeaders:requestheaders];

NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"REQUEST=%@",string];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonString UTF8String] length:[jsonString length]];

[asiRequest setPostBody:[NSMutableData dataWithData:requestData]];
[asiRequest addData:imageData forKey:@"logo"];

[asiRequest setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[asiRequest setDelegate:self];
[asiRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[asiRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
[asiRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];
[asiRequest startAsynchronous];
```

If you have any idea where I am wrong people let me know. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try like below, no need to do any thing other than this.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_URL_TO_POST"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"img.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"logo"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

and write delegate methods like,

```
- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{    

     NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
     NSLog( @"response--%@",responseString );

 }
- (void)uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

  NSLog(@" Error - Statistics file upload failed: \"%@\"",[[request error]   localizedDescription]);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks @murali, but I have to send the json request as well with the image data, the json request includes the api_username, api_password and a method parameter which is user_id. If you have any idea on how to send json dictionary with image data please let me know. Thanks much.